# Submit a form from a loaded page

Tags: ajax, jquery

I want to submit a form which belongs to a loaded page (I use load()). When I click onto the button submission, nothing happens.

Html code of the loaded page:

```
    <form id="my_form" method="post" >
         *** some inputs ***
        <input id="submit_button" type="submit" value="Confirm" />
    </form>
```

jQuery code of the loaded page:

```
$("#submit_button").on('click', function() {        

    $('#my_form').submit(function(){ 
        var myForm = $(this);       

        $.ajax({
            dataType: 'json',               
            type: "POST",
            url: "../treatment_page.php", 
            data:myForm.serialize(),
            success: function(data){
                    if (data.a == true){
                          parent.$.colorbox.close();
                    }else{
                         alert("Problem!");
                    }          
            }
        });                 
    return false;       

    });

});
```

treatment_page.php is OK, it treats my others forms don't usnig on(). treatment_page.php is into a parent folder.  All the jQuery actions work fine in the loaded page script except this form submission.

Comment: what about using `.on('submit', ...);`

Comment: Move the `submit` event handler outside of the `click` event handler. Then remove the `click` event handler all together since it's unnecessary (just bind to the `submit` event since the submit button submits the form anyway).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On submit button click you are just attaching a `submit` handler to form. You don't need the submit button click handler. Just keep this code on the parent page and also rendering this script along with `load` response is not required.

```
$(document).on('submit', '#my_form', function(){ 
        var myForm = $(this);       

        $.ajax({
            dataType: 'json',               
            type: "POST",
            url: "../treatment_page.php", 
            data:myForm.serialize(),
            success: function(data){
                    if (data.a == true){
                          parent.$.colorbox.close();
                    }else{
                         alert("Problem!");
                    }          
            },
            error: function(){
                //Error handler
            }
        });                 
    return false;       

});
```

`on` is introduced in jQuery 1.7 if you are using older version then you can use `delegate`. Try this.

```
$(document).delegate('#my_form', 'submit', function(){ 
        ....
        ....
});
```

Comment: I use jQuery 1.7 and on() works fine with others actions. i try your solutions without success. Except "success", how can I catch ajax exceptions ? I'd like to see errors to help myself...

Comment: You can use the `error` handler. Added error handler in my answer check out.

Comment: What is the error you are getting if you use my code? Is it making a ajax call?

Comment: I've just used the error handler with alert(xhr.responseText); . It indicates me a 404 error, the problem was in the url (I use MVC...). Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Move the onSubmit handler outside the click handler.

```
$('#my_form').submit(function(){ 
    var myForm = $(this);       

    $.ajax({
        dataType: 'json',               
        type: "POST",
        url: "../treatment_page.php", 
        data:myForm.serialize(),
        success: function(data){
                if (data.a == true){
                      parent.$.colorbox.close();
                }else{
                     alert("Problem!");
                }          
        }
    });                 
return false;       

});
```

Comment: hi, as the form was 'not there to begin with' i think you would have to use `.on('submit')` or `.delegate('submit')` or `.live('submit')` depending on version rather then trying to `.bind('submit')` to an element that isn't there unless the form was created using a jQuery object which I don't think it has been